# File is damaged when Flex is writing stream

Tags: apache-flex, download

I'm get file content on my host and save the file via this functions:

```
protected function fileDownload(fileName:String):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteFileDownload);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("http://samed.us/"+fileName));
}
private function onCompleteFileDownload(e:Event):void
{
    saveFile("test.jpg",URLLoader(e.target).data);
}
private var Depo:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("testFiles");
private function saveFile(fileName:String, content:String):void
{
    var file:* = Depo.resolvePath(fileName);
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes(content);
    stream.close();
}
```

For example, [this image](http://samed.us/bg2.jpg) can be displayed. But functions are downloads and writes by disrupting.

How fix?

Comment: Use Ex.: fileDownload("bg2.jpg");

Comment: You should write your edit as an answer to your question and accept it, so people will know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. Fix functions:

```
protected function fileDownload(fileName:String):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteFileDownload);
    loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    loader.load(new URLRequest("http://samed.us/"+fileName));
}
private function onCompleteFileDownload(e:Event):void
{
    saveFile("test.jpg",(e.target).data);
}

private var Depo:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("testFiles");
private function saveFile(fileName:String, content:*):void
{
    var file:* = Depo.resolvePath(fileName);
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeBytes(content);
    stream.close();
}
```

The source of the problem: UTF & Binary.